# HTML anchors and asynchronous image loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, asynchronous, anchor

What is the right way to keep track of an html anchor while non static sized pictures are loading? to prevent the page to jump around after each picture is loaded.

CSS:

```
img.non_static{
    width:100%
    height: auto;
}
```

If someone used a link with an anchor:

```
randomlink.php?id=x#element
```

The page jumps to the anchored element but as soon as some pictures are loaded the pagesize changes and the anchored Element moves around depending on the image size.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Nope. You are plumb out of luck, unless your images come in standard sizes so that you can apply default CSS styles to them based on class names.

Comment: I could use a callback function for the imageloader but that would not be very usefull with large imagetransfers. Another way would be a jump to the anchor after every image or after all images are loaded. Guess I have to do it this way. Thanks.